# PostGIS shp2pgsql-gui with Windows 10 Enterprise crash when running

Tags: postgis, shapefile, import

Using shp2pgsql-gui on Windows 10 Enterprise to import shapefile data, crashes systematically on some files; for some files, this does not happen.

[image: shapefile import configuration for a file that crashes]

No error message is sent.

Does anyone know the reason?  Is there an alternate ways to basically import shapefiles?

The files come from our government and are widely used.

Comment: How large are your shapefiles that you are having issues with? Have you verified that there are no empty geometries or corrupt files?

Answer (score 2):

You can use shp2pgsql which is the commandline equivalent.  Actually has more features than the gui.

It should be in the bin folder of your PostgreSQL install.

http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#shp2pgsql_usage

You can also use QGIS DBManager to load the file.

If it's a specific file and you can provide a link to it, I can take a look at it and see what the issue is.  You can also use our ticketing to report the issue - http://postgis.net/support/